# Android download manager unsuccessful error

Tags: android, download

I have been facing this problem for specific urls. Whenever I try to download the file with android manager, I get download unsuccessful error.When I try the same link with other download manager say ES File Downloader, it's working perfectly.

Here is my code for downloading from a URI.

```
try{
    uri = Uri.parse(urls.get(countLinks));
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Caught inside uri", e.toString());
    }
```

And the download manager here

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
            DownloadManager.Request songDownload = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            songDownload.setTitle(title);
            songDownload.setDescription("Simple Mp3 Downloader...");
            songDownload.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            songDownload.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC, (title+".mp3") );
            songDownload.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(songDownload);
```

There is no error shown in logcat during the process. But download manager shows unsuccessful.
 : [Here is a sample link](http://dl2.farskids532.com/Masoud/1392/10/04/1/Enrique%20Iglesias%20Ft.%20Gente%20De%20Zona%20&%20Descember%20Bueno%20-%20Bailando.mp3)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself, I had to replace the spaces in the url by %20 and it worked. I would suggest using URLEncoder though.

```
String s = url.replaceAll(" " , "%20");
Uri link = Uri.parse(s);
```